# float:right pushed down the caret when content is too long, how to make work?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- import bootstrap 4 css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--import local css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/common_style.css">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
      <!-- Top navbar-->
      <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <!-- Navbar brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="*">Navbar</a>
        <!-- Collapse button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topNav">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- Collapsible content -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Test </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Test </a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"> Test 1 </a>
                  <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">JavaScript</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Bootstrap</a></li>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="">Other </a>
                      <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Multi level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Multi level 2</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"> Test 2 </a>
                  <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">JavaScript</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Bootstrap</a></li>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="">Other </a>
                      <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Multi level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Multi level 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Other </a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">  More items  </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Dropdown item 1 </a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"> Dropdown item 2 with extra words </a>
                  <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">JavaScript</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Bootstrap</a></li>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="">Other </a>
                      <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Multi level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Multi level 2</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"> Dropdown item 3 </a>
                  <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Another submenu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Another submenu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Another submenu 3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Another submenu 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"> Dropdown item 4 </a>
                  <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Another submenu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Another submenu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Another submenu 3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Another submenu 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Dropdown item 4 </a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Dropdown item 5 </a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Links -->
          <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
            <div class="md-form my-0"> <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Css:

```
/*Mult-level dropdown menu css*/
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .dropdown-menu li {
        position: relative;
    }
    .dropdown-menu:hover > li:hover > .submenu {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle:after {
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        margin-top: 10px;
        float: right;
    }
    .nav-item .submenu { 
        display: none;
        left:100%; 
        top:-8px;
    }
}
```

Snipping:
[image]

Run on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nLcq9b62/1/

As you can see, the caret been pushed down because of float:right, but if remove float:right will align caret next to the content, which is not desired.

How can i right align caret while caret not been pushed down? Also, I want keep code simple and easy, so make as little changes as possible will be very nice.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the line is so long that the float right caret can't fit in? Where do you want the line to break?

Comment: Don't use float. Add some padding to your `.dropdown-toggle` element and position the caret absolutely.

Comment: I would like the line is extended so the right caret will be fit in, if I set .dropdown-toggle to absolute, then add the padding, then it will have different location, the right caret will not be align right at same position.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I find a way.
By setting `.dropdown-toggle` to `absolute` and position it to `right:10px` fixed it. Thanks for help.